# What port does elasticsearch listen on when installed via homebrew?

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, homebrew

I'm using Mac 10.13.6.  I just installed elasticsearch via homebrew and launched it ...

```
brew services start elasticsearch
Service `elasticsearch` already started, use `brew services restart elasticsearch` to restart.
```

In my /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml configuration file, I have

```
http.port: 9200
```

However, when I attempt to see if that port is available, I get a connection refused ...

```
localhost:tmp davea$ telnet localhost 9200
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

What port is elasticsearch getting launched on and how can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

That may be the problem of Mac firewall? Edit elasticsearch.yml file in elasticsearch/config folder. Change the localhost to 127.0.0.1  to take a try?

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
```

Comment: I changed the elasticsearch per your suggestion (previously it was defined as "network.host: 192.168.0.1") but sadly I still fail to connect on telnet after I run "brew services restart elasticsearch".

Comment: If there is any space before http.port: 9200, it's not gonna work.